# Why flutter app showing slow mode in top right?

Tags: android, flutter

Actually, I'm new to flutter and when i installed my first app its showing me `slow mode` in top right why it is showing like this?

[image: Image for explain more]

This question may also can be stupid but, I'm just asking this to increase my own knowledge

Comment: Check this for solution : https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-2-do-not-display-the-debug-or-slow-mode-banner/

Answer (score 2):

You can look to 
[debugShowCheckedModeBanner property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/debugShowCheckedModeBanner.html)

> Turns on a little "DEBUG" banner in checked mode to indicate that the app is in checked mode. This is on by default (in checked mode), to turn it off, set the constructor argument to false. In release mode this has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can place

```
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

inside the MaterialApp

[see here api.flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/debugShowCheckedModeBanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's showing that banner because your app is in debug mode. Flutter uses fundamentally different optimisations between its Debug and Release builds.

Debug builds are optimised for development speed and hot-reloading - as soon as you edit a widget, you see the change reflected on your device. The tradeoff is that debug apps take a lot longer to launch from the app drawer.

Release builds are optimised for better user experience. They do not support hot-reloading of code, but they start quicker, use less storage and generally have better UI performance.

As @ChristianVirtual already said, you can disable that banner by adding this to your `MaterialApp` widget:

```
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

If you want to learn more, you should read up on the build modes documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes